# How to avoid giving autoreconf in yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a source code which is using autotools to compile.Where autoreconf will not work.Which requires only 1."aclocal" 2."autoconf" 3."automake -a 2>&1 | grep -vF Makefile.am". While inheriting autotools in bitbake file automatically it is doing autoreconf and throwing the error

"autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
 ERROR: autoreconf execution failed."

So how to avoid autoreconf command getting automatically invoked once autotools is inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autoreconf just calls aclocal/automake/autoconf for you.  If you can share the actual error then it might be an easy fix.

Comment: ERROR: cfssm-1.0-1.0-r0 do_configure: autoreconf execution failed.
ERROR: cfssm-1.0-1.0-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at poky/rpi-build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/cfssm-1.0/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.30494)

autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
ERROR: autoreconf execution failed.

Comment: All of the log, not just the bit that said "i failed".  All of log.do_configure in a pastebin, please.

Comment: As your recipe is called cfssm you can remove the S assignment (as that's the default). You can also remove do_install (as that's the default).

Comment: The log says 'automake: error: no 'Makefile.am' found for any configure output'. If there's meant to be a Makefile.am then check the tarball is extracting into the right place.

Comment: Actually in that autotools compilation there is no Makefile.am. It is just compiled using the commands which I have mentioned above. 1.aclocal  2.autoconf  3."automake -a 2>&1 | grep -vF Makefile.am" in this what is the meaning of the third command and how to override with this argument in do_configure_append() or any other function.

Comment: EXTRA_AUTORECONF += "--exclude=automake"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply override do_configure in your recipe. Just implement something like this:
do_configure () {

}

But you might want to check why autoreconf fails... a proper fix would be a cleaner solution.